# Using VBA - Insert VLOOKUP depending on certain values

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to retrieve data from another file using the VLOOKUP function however this is only to happen depending on if any of the 3 items of data appear in column 8(H)

OLY

OLY - QUO

OLY - PRO

---

I have the following and know this is not correct

```
Sub BlockAllocationsVlookupAll()

Dim x As Long
For x = 1 To 65536

If InStr(1, Sheet1.Range("$H$" & x), "OLY") > 0 Then
Sheet1.Range("$I$" & x) = Sheet1.Range("$I$" & x) & "sometext"
End If
Next

End Sub
```

I know the above doesn't do exactly what I need can anyone help as to what needs to be edited to include the Vlookup below

```
=VLOOKUP(A21,'[001 - Allocations - Blocks.xls]CurrentDayAll'!$1:$65536,9,FALSE)
```

The other issue is that the cell the VLOOKUP points to first will also change due to the varying length of the report

Thank you for any help given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD:**

As follows up from comments,

- column `H` is in Allocations.xls workbook
- there are a set of criterias
- formula should be placed in cell only if corresponding cell in column `H` matches any of thouse criterias.

---

Working code:

```
Sub BlockAllocationsVlookupAll()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim searchCriterias As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'specify correct path to your workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Allocations.xls")
    'If workbook is already opened use next line
    'Set wb = Workbooks("Allocations.xls")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Current Day")

    searchCriterias = "|OLY|SVC|SVC-PRO|SVC-QUO|EUR|EUR-PRO|EUR-QUO|"

    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

        For x = 4 To lastrow
            If InStr(1, searchCriterias, "|" & .Range("H" & x) & "|") > 0 Then
                .Range("I" & x).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A" & x & ",'[001 - Allocations - Blocks.xls]CurrentDayAll'!$A:$I,9,FALSE)"
            End If
        Next
    End With

    'Comment next line if you don't want to close wb
    wb.Close (True)
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the coding above but will this only look at OLY and not the other two (OLY - QUO & OLY - PRO)

Comment: as I see it should also work with OLY - QUO and OLY - PRO as well (since OLY is substring of thouse strings). `If InStr(1, .Range("H" & x), "OLY") > 0 Then` looks if `range("H" & x)` **contains** OLY. Btw, if you don't like it, change `If InStr(1, .Range("H" & x), "OLY") > 0 Then` to `If InStr(1, .Range("H" & x), "OLY")+InStr(1, .Range("H" & x), "OLY - QUO")+InStr(1, .Range("H" & x), "OLY - PRO") > 0 Then
`

Comment: basically, if cell contains OLY - QUO or OLY - PRO, it also means that cell contains OLY. So, all you need is to check whether cell contains OLY.

Comment: Ah ok I see, so will this only pick up the bits of data suggested above.  I.e. I have other bits of data that would come after OLY - QUO like SVC - QUO.  If I wanted to add more into the search how would I do this - eg SVC, SVC - PRO, SVC - QUO, EUR, EUR - PRO, EUR - QUO

Comment: there is one trick..see my updated answer. Just split all criterias usign "|" sign (or any other rare sign) in variable `searchCriterias`.

Comment: I have amended a few items but am unable to get it working - can you have a look at the code and let me know where I've made a mistake, its probably so obvious.

Comment: Sure, what problem exactly do you have?

Comment: The spreadsheet where the Vlookup needs to be entered is - Allocations.xls - Sheet is: Current Day - First cell is in row 4 - I have amended what I thought was the right bits but unfortunately not

Comment: Yes that is correct the criteria is in allocations.xls

Comment: There is one other thing the workbook is already open when this code runs is there a better way of selecting it other than closing and re-opening?

Comment: just change `Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Allocations.xls")` to `Set wb = Workbooks("Allocations.xls")` and remove line `wb.close (True)`

Comment: Do you know of any reason why once I have ran it once it will not run again? I have even tried removing all the code and putting it back - does this change anything in the cells to stop it from working again?

Comment: It works for me as expected..have you removed `wb.Close (True)` line?

Comment: Yes I have removed it

Comment: What heppens with your code when you run it second time? have you tried to debug it? What error have you got? Specify please symptoms

Comment: It doesn't come up with an error - I removed the vlookups after the first run so I could check that when I have made the changes as per the "Just change" comment and all seems to run ok but the vlookups do not get put back in the allocations.xls spreadsheet as before.

Comment: try my updated asnwer..I've changed `If InStr(1, "|" & CStr(.Range("H" & x)) & "|", searchCriterias) > 0 Then` to `If Not IsError(Application.Find("|" & .Range("H" & x).Value & "|", searchCriterias)) Then`

Comment: That seems to have solved the issue - many thanks and sorry to have been a pain!